Language inconsistency in The Expanse
The adjective of the planet Mars is Martian (note the s changes to a t). This is part of common knowledge, and it is in use in the Expanse novels.
The adjective of the planet Jupiter is Jovian (the exclamation "By Jove!" might be a more known example of this declination quirk). This is nowhere near as commonly known, but nonetheless it is in use in the novels.
The adjective of the planet Venus is Veneral. This is, I would think, more well-known than Jupiter, but nonetheless it is not used in the novels (in particular in the second novel, Caliban's War, where the sun's second planet is more in focus).
Does anyone know the reason that S. A. Corey did it this way?

I believe it's "Venereal" not "Veneral" and the reason it's not preferred is likely the reason that IRL "Venusian" has largely supplanted it; the association with STDs.

I can't compare "venusian" to "venereal" because the conflict with the medical meaning, but here is a comparison of "venusian" to "venerian" and "venerean" showing how popular "venusian" has been for many years.

“By Jove” is not a contraction of Jovian, it’s a contraction of Jehova. It’s a method of swearing without using the Lord’s name.

@DaleM: I disagree, and so does Merriam-Webster. But you are right that Jove doesn't derive from Jovian; it's the other way round $-$ Jovian derives from Jove. In Latin, the oblique stem of Iuppiter is Iov- (both of those start with upper-case 'i').

First, I want to clarify that you're probably looking for "venerean" rather than "venereal."  "Venereal" suggests partaking of the traits of Venus, like "jovial" comes from Jupiter (Jove) and "martial" comes from Mars.  The equivalent adjectival forms describing the planets (and hence their demonyms) are "venerean," "jovian," and "martian" respectively.
Given that, this Google Ngram query shows that "Venusian" has been much more popular than the combination of "Venerean" and "Venerian," except briefly from about 1925-1935, for more than two centuries.  As such, Corey's choice of "Venusian" is simply following common usage.


Since it is common usage, it presumably would have been the default choice in-universe too...

You're entirely right that I chose the wrong form of the word and also spelled it wrongly. That one is on me. This data does explain the authors' choice, but I still find it curious how that one planet (and god) lost its old form and not the other two.

@Arthur That might be a good question on the English Language and Usage Stack Exchange.

@Arthur I figure usually boils down to "English is like that."  After all, considering traits that use gods' names as descriptors, we have mercurial, venereal, martial, jovial ...and saturnine.  At some point all you can do is shrug and say "well, English, you know?"

@DavidW Thank you for this! It appears "Venusian" trampled the competition a century ago. :)
